# JS concatenating object property values (numeric) instead of adding

Tags: javascript

In an intersect function, that checks if two objects intersect on the canvas, I need to add the obj.x and obj.width property to get the obj.right(side). Somehow the properties are concatenated instead of added. It probably has something to do with reference-type but I don't see how I can capture the values in primitive types.

```
function intersects(obj1, obj2) { // checks if 2 shapes intersect
    var ob2x = obj2.x;
    var ob2width = obj2.width;
    if (obj1.x > +obj2.x + 70 || obj2.x > +obj1.x + 70) {
        console.log('false : obj1.x=' + obj1.x + '     obj2.right=' + parseInt(ob2x) + parseInt(ob2width));
        return false;
    }

    if (obj1.y > +obj2.y + +obj2.height || obj2.y > +obj1.y + +obj1.height) {
        console.log('false');
        return false;
    }

    console.log('false');
    return true;
}
```

I have already tried to get the number value of the object property, as you can see. Didn't work

Also tried parseInt(), which didn't work.

I suppose I can put the values seperately as parameters in the fuctions but I was hoping to keep it as short as possible, because kids need to use it.

Comment: Instead of just dumping a lump of code in front of us, can you tell us which part isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a grouping operator:

```
 ... + (parseInt(ob2x) + parseInt(ob2width)) + ...
```

to isolate that part of the expression so that `+` is seen as addition. Otherwise, the full expression keeps it as concatenation, even though you convert those to values to numbers (because if a string is anywhere in the expression being evaluated, + means concat).

E.g.

```
var x = 5;
var y = 6;

console.log('Sum: ' + x + y);   // 56

console.log('Sum: ' + (x + y)); // 11
```

Comment: How ridiculously simple. Thanks a lot. That saves me a lot of frustration.